# Using WMI to query Windows Event Collector logs

Tags: windows-event-log, wmi

Using WMI to query the eventlog is quite simple, using Win32_NTLogEvent, for example:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT *FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE (logfile='Application' and SourceName='Something')
```

However, if i want to query a log that contains events collected with Windows Event Collector, they don't show up in the results, even tho events from other sources in the same log does.

I can use  the cmdlet `Get-Eventlog` to retrieve WEC events, but that does not solve my problem.

What i am trying to do, is to use the `__InstanceCreationEvent` and do something (forward it to a kafka instance) when a new event is inserted in the log. See [example from Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/01/19/how-can-i-be-notified-when-a-process-begins.aspx) and [Logstash Eventlog input module](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-eventlog/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/eventlog.rb#L54) for example usage.

```
$query = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' And (TargetInstance.LogFile = 'HardwareEvents')"
$Eventwatcher = New-Object management.managementEventWatcher $Query
$Event = $Eventwatcher.waitForNextEvent()
```

This works perfectly for normal logs, but not with forwarded events from Windows Event Collector.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On your Event Subscription, if you set the "Destination Log" to "System", AND if you do NOT specify `logfile` in your `WHERE` condition, then the forwarded events will show up in the results. This is totally weird.